Cross filter through slicer
I want a slicer in my Power BI dashboard to filter a table visual. But this slicer is about a table ("StructuresInMarket") which is not in a direct "1 to many" relationship with the table in the target table visual ("Events"). So "as is" it doesn't work.
I can solve the problem by switching the relationships from the table "StructuresInMarket" to bidirectional. But I read it's not a good practice.
So I tried to call a measure in a column in the table visual showing "Events", to force the use of CROSSFILTER(). But it doesn't work.
Does somebody know how to do this?
What is exactly the problem if I use a bidirectional relationship?
Thank you.

